# jQuery get div's height on ready&resize

Tags: jquery, height

I have 2 separate functions to get one element's height and apply it onto its child. So basically the function repeats itself on when document ready and on window resize. Is there any better way to make it?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var height = $('#sgn-panel-friendslist-holder').height();
    $("#sgn-panel-friendslist-holder #scroll").css("height", height-24)
});


$( window ).resize(function() {
    var height = $('#sgn-panel-friendslist-holder').height();
    $("#sgn-panel-friendslist-holder #scroll").css("height", height-24)
});
```

Comment: That's how I've always done it. I don't 'think there is really a "Better" way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is better code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).resize(function() {
      var height = $('#sgn-panel-friendslist-holder').height();
      $("#sgn-panel-friendslist-holder #scroll").css("height", height-24)
   }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: Nope. this doesn't work.  This event only triggers when the window (browser) is re-sized, and not when the page is loaded..  This only just triggers itself twice.

Comment: I don't think so, It's work fine. You should try again. When the page loaded, it's call resize window automatically. Instead we duplicate code.

And this block code will put on $(document).ready. Full source:
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(window).resize(function() {
   var height = $('#sgn-panel-friendslist-holder').height();
   $("#sgn-panel-friendslist-holder #scroll").css("height", height-24)
}).trigger('resize');
});

Comment: Yes, I see.. This code in the `$(document).ready() {` works because of the .trigger('resize'). you are right. I'm sorry..

Comment: I originally down-voted your answer and it wont let me take it back unless you edit your answer..  just edit something/anything in your answer and I will remove the down-vote.  apologies.  :)

Comment: @Bryan Elliott I often use this way, because it's short and clean code. Have a nice weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is always "different" ways and approaches to code something and get the same result, and in this case, to say which one is "better" or "more efficient" isn't as certain as it may be in other coding problems and/or scenarios..

for example: You could take your duplicate code within .ready and .resize events and put then into a single function, like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   setHeight();
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
   setHeight();
});

function setHeight() {
   var height = $('#sgn-panel-friendslist-holder').height();
   $("#sgn-panel-friendslist-holder #scroll").css("height", height-24);
}
```

But now the question is: Is that really any "better" or "more efficient"? Others may have their opinion, but in my opinion.. No.  Does it save time or save lines of code? My opinion.. No.  Is it structurally easier to read, understand, and debug?  My opinion.. No.

So there ya go..  Is there a "better way"?  In my opinion. No.. not really.